# Ayuda al crear carpetas y archivos .txt

Tags: java

tengo esta tarea donde mi programa debe leer cuantas carpetas y cuantos archivos hay en dicha carpeta, aparte de leer cuantos hay de cada tipo debe crear 4 nuevas carpetas y en cada carpeta crear 4 archivos texto. Primero pues debe crear las 4 carpetas y 4 archivos en dichas carpetas antes de leer, alguien que me pueda ayudar, logre hacer el codigo para que lea los archivos pero de lo otro ocupo un poco de ayuda, gracias

```
  import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     *
     * @author carli
     */
    public class JavaApplication5 {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here

            File miDir = new File("C:\\users\\carli\\desktop\\Directorios"); 
            verContenidoFolder(miDir);
        }

        public static void verContenidoFolder(File dir) {
            int directorio = 0;
            int archivo = 0;

            try {
                File[] files = dir.listFiles();
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        System.out.println("directorio:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                        verContenidoFolder(file);
                        directorio++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("     archivo:" + file.getCanonicalPath());

                        archivo++;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("TOTAL DE DIRECTORIOS--- :" + directorio);
            System.out.println("TOTAL DE ARCHIVOS------ :" + archivo);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver el contenido de todos los documentos y directorios de una carpeta puedes usar este algoritmo.

```
public List<Path> listarDirectoriosyArchivosRapido(String rutaBase) {
    Stream<Path> directorios = null;

    try {
        Path rutaNormalizada = this.normalizarRuta(rutaBase);
        System.out.println("Privilegios: -> Lectura = "+Files.isReadable(rutaNormalizada));

        directorios = Files.walk(rutaNormalizada, 1, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



    return directorios.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

En cuanto al hecho de crear una carpeta puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
Files.createFile(Paths.get("ruta del archivo"));
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("ruta del directorio"));
```

Comment: Muchisimias gracias, esto me ayudo!